# When controlling a remote computer in a Lync presentation, my local keyboard layout is ignored

Tags: keyboard-layout, remote-access, lync, lync-2010

When remoting into a computer using RDP, GoTo Assist, Bomgar, and most other assistance tools the local keyboard layout is properly translated to the remote computer. However, when taking control of a computer during a Lync presentation the keyboard layout is not honored, and typing uses the remote computer's active layout.

Is there a setting in Lync that resolves this, or is there an alternative workaround that allows typing to properly use the local keyboard mapping regardless of the capabilities of the tool used? Bonus points if the fix [works for SCCM as well](https://superuser.com/questions/680882/when-remoting-into-a-computer-using-sccm-my-local-keyboard-layout-is-ignored).

Comment: I discovered this to my chagrin yesterday when I tried to do some remote diagnostics and my Dvorak keystrokes were turning up as gibberish on the other end. It was hunt and peck time for a while...